# How can I get folder inside Jar as File object?

Tags: java, file, jar, directory, resources

I would to get a folder of resources inside the .jar file, when I execute from that, as File object (or alternatively File[] object with all files inside of the folder)

How can I?

EDIT
I tried with

```
File dir = new File(ClassName.getClass().getResources(path).toURI());
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried any code or made any attempt at this?

Comment: Hint: A jar is essentially a `ZipFile`

Comment: sorry, I edited with my (failed) attempt